# Overflowing text in cvskill in Awesome-CV

Tags: tables, cv, resume, awesome-cv

I am trying to format my cv using the awesome-cv.cls. The cvskills are overflowing. Can someone please help me on how to wrap the texts? I have changed the cvskills environment a little bit:

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{3}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is your complete tex code. You have put only a fragment.

Comment: Hi the whole class is here: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before `\begin{document}` (and using the original class)

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newlength{\category}
\settowidth{\category}{Database \& query languages} % Category with longer text 
\renewenvironment{cvskills}{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    \vspace{-2.0mm}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} R{\category-2\tabcolsep} L{\textwidth -\category -2\tabcolsep}} % changed <<<<<<<<
        }{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
}
```

This will accommodate the widest  "Category" of skill in the left column and use the remaining space for the "Skills".

[image: c]

This is the file `skills.tex` used in this example

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsection{Skills}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cvskills}

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Programming languages} % Category
    {As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
        practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
        in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
        used as a canon for our understanding.} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {ML/AI libraries} % Category
    {Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
        with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
        posteriori.} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Database \& query languages} % Category
    {Our concepts have lying before them the
        paralogisms of natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have
        lying before them the practical employment of our experience.} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Development tools} % Category
    { As I have shown elsewhere, Aristotle tells
        us that the objects in space and time, in the full sense of these
        terms, would be falsified.} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Frameworks} % Category
    {Node.js, Python, JAVA, OCaml, LaTeX} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cvskills}
```